# run and update dynamic array every x minute

Tags: java

I have array with size of 80000, the array updates itself in infinity loop,
and has about 1000+/- hits per second in O(1).

i need to create function that run every one minute exactly and what the  function does is go through all the dynamic array and update a particular field inside every cell in the array.

How can I create that function that running on dynamic array?

maybe with threads?

Comment: you have make it more clear, current question didn't describe your problem.

Comment: Your sample code would not compile as well.

Answer (score 1):

To create function that run every one minute you can use [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for that

Whether to use Thread or not depends on your business logic 
(How you are updating array ,can  it be in background,is it updated from network(Web service call)?. etc).use Thread only you need to improve responsiveness of your proceess/application